# A question about the derivative of trace involving Hadamard product

Tags: matrices, derivatives, hadamard-product

Assume that $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\geq 0$, $Y\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times k}\geq 0$ and $Z\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times n}\geq 0$. Let us define the function $f(Y,Z)$ as follows:
$$f(Y,Z)=\Vert X-YZ\Vert_W^2:=\mathrm{trace}\left((X-YZ)^T(W\circ(X-YZ))\right),$$
where $\circ$ is the Hadamard product and $W\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\geq 0$ is symmetric.

It can be seen that
\begin{align*}
f(Y,Z)&=\mathrm{trace}\left((X^T-Z^TY^T)(W\circ(X-YZ))\right)\\
&=\mathrm{trace}(X^T(W\circ X))-\mathrm{trace}(X^T(W\circ (YZ)))-\mathrm{trace}(Z^TY^T(W\circ X))
+\mathrm{trace}(Z^TY^T(W\circ (YZ))).
\end{align*}
Now, according to the fact that $\mathrm{trace}(AB)=\mathrm{trace}(BA)$, and $\mathrm{trace}(A^T(B\circ C)=trace((A\circ B)^TC)$, it follows that
$$f(Y,Z)=\mathrm{trace}(X^T(W\circ X))-2\mathrm{trace}(Z^TY^T(W\circ X))
+\mathrm{trace}(Z^TY^T(W\circ (YZ))).$$

**I have a question about the derivative of $f$ with respect to $Y$ or $Z$.** To this end, we have
$$\frac{\partial \mathrm{trace}(Z^TY^T(W\circ X))}{\partial Y}=(W\circ X)Z^T,\quad and\quad \frac{\partial \mathrm{trace}(Z^TY^T(W\circ X))}{\partial Z}=Y^T(W\circ X).$$

What can it be said about the following items?
$$\frac{\partial \mathrm{trace}(Z^TY^T(W\circ (YZ)))}{\partial Y},\quad and\quad\frac{\partial \mathrm{trace}(Z^TY^T(W\circ (YZ)))}{\partial Z}.$$

I would be appreciate if someone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we define $\phi=\mathrm{trace}(Z^TY^T(W\circ (YZ)))$ and $A=YZ$, it can be observed that
$$\phi=\mathrm{trace}(Z^TY^T(W\circ (YZ)))=\mathrm{trace}(A^T(W\circ A)).$$
For more convenience, let's define
$\mathrm{trace}(C^TD)=C:D$. Hence,
\begin{align*}
\phi=W\circ A:A,
\end{align*}
and we can conclude that
\begin{align*}
d\phi&=2W\circ A:dA\\
&=2W\circ (YZ):d(YZ)\\
&=2W\circ (YZ):(dY\,\,Z+Y\,\,dZ)\\
&=2(W\circ (YZ))Z^T:dY+2Y^T(W\circ (UV)):dZ.
\end{align*}
As a consequence, we get
\begin{align*}
&\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial Y}=2(W\circ (YZ))Z^T,\\
&\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial Z}=2Y^T(W\circ (UV)).
\end{align*}

Comment: +1  In terms of the OP's original function these gradients become
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y} &= 2\Big[W\circ(YZ-X)\Big]Z^T \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial Z} &= 2Y^T\Big[W\circ(YZ-X)\Big] \\
}$$ Also the variables $(U,V)$ appear to be a cut-and-paste error

Comment: @greg, Thank you so much.